# Frequent Daily Panics - El Capitan, MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

Product Information:

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
OS X El Capitan
3 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Macintosh HD
Intel Iris 1536 MB
```

My MBP is encountering multiple panic's daily. I have explored Panic Report, but I am chasing shadows, looking for errors in incorrect components. Could someone please have a quick look and see if there is anything that looks odd?

```
Anonymous UUID:       C54CD30F-CD0A-E69A-3574-1C8049689627  


Mon Feb 15 11:36:31 2016  


*** Panic Report ***  
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff8008dd255a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800904a0ec, type 13=general protection, registers:  
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x000000011d837000, CR3: 0x000000000bfbe000, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0  
RAX: 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef, RBX: 0xffffff8034656e00, RCX: 0xffffffff117ce7c2, RDX: 0x0000000000000001  
RSP: 0xffffff81e7d538f0, RBP: 0xffffff81e7d53970, RSI: 0x0000000000000002, RDI: 0xffffff8027682900  
R8:  0xffffff8027680000, R9:  0xffffff8038ecc138, R10: 0x0000000000000278, R11: 0x0000137ae41b8315  
R12: 0xffffff8038ecbb18, R13: 0x0000000000000001, R14: 0xffffff8038ecc138, R15: 0xffffff8034656f68  
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0xffffff800904a0ec, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010  
Fault CR2: 0x000000011d837000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x3, PL: 0  


Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address  
0xffffff81e7d4ddf0 : 0xffffff8008cdf792  
0xffffff81e7d4de70 : 0xffffff8008dd255a  
0xffffff81e7d4e050 : 0xffffff8008df0233  
0xffffff81e7d4e070 : 0xffffff800904a0ec  
0xffffff81e7d53970 : 0xffffff8009046d26  
0xffffff81e7d53d90 : 0xffffff80090334f7  
0xffffff81e7d53de0 : 0xffffff8009034a33  
0xffffff81e7d53f40 : 0xffffff8008f69f5c  
0xffffff81e7d53fb0 : 0xffffff8008dccf77  


BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task  


Mac OS version:  
15D21  


Kernel version:  
Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64  
Kernel UUID: DECC9F02-27D7-31F0-9599-A9EF2873902C  
Kernel slide:     0x0000000008a00000  
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8008c00000  
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8008b00000  
System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC)  


System uptime in nanoseconds: 21418533994494  
last loaded kext at 21001069059496: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8ba1d000, size 12288)  
last unloaded kext at 18742076878601: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C 2.0.59 (addr 0xffffff7f8b132000, size 36864)  
loaded kexts:  
com.parallels.kext.vnic 11.1.2 32408  
com.parallels.kext.netbridge 11.1.2 32408  
com.parallels.kext.hypervisor 11.1.2 32408  
com.parallels.kext.usbconnect 11.1.2 32408  
com.fortinet.fct.kext.fctapnke 1  
com.fortinet.fct.kext.avkern 1.0.1  
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp 5.0.6  
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt 5.0.6  
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.6  
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.6  
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch 90.3  
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet 10.1.12  
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.0  
com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0  
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70  
com.apple.driver.AGPM 110.20.22  
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.6.0d0  
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim 1.0.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 272.51.3  
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.6.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1  
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry 1  
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.4.3f4  
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics 10.1.2  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8  
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 3.1  
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleHV 1  
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4  
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 208  
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul 10.1.2  
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface 5.41.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.8  
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.2.13  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 245.4  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4  
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1  
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0  
com.apple.BootCache 38  
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.8.5  
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 3.1.8  
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360 1020.17.1a1  
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 4.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8  
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 4.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7  
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 163  
com.apple.security.quarantine 3  
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 900.4.1  
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver 4.4.3f4  
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver 304.10  
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport 5  
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter 2.0.2  
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1  
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0  
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3  
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 525  
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 108.0.1  
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder 1  
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4  
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.4.3f4  
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3  
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3  
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 204.3  
com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0  
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0  
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7  
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.12.6  
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 205.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily 1.0.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11  
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.1.0  
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.4.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9  
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.14d1  
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.4.1  
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.7.7  
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver 1.0.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.7.7  
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5  
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 900.4.1  
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage 517.20.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.8.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter 4.1.3  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily 4.1.3  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2  
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI 4.0.4  
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0  
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 1110.26  
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8  
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.2  
com.apple.driver.corecapture 1.0.4  
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI 1.0.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties 1.0.1  
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0  
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1  
com.apple.security.sandbox 300.0  
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1  
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2  
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5  
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0  
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2  
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1  
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 31  
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30  
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 4.0  
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9  
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4  
com.apple.kec.Libm 1  
com.apple.kec.pthread 1  
com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0  
Model: MacBookPro11,1, BootROM MBP111.0138.B16, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.16f68  
Graphics: Intel Iris, Intel Iris, Built-In  
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020  
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020  
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x112), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.94.136.1a1)  
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.3f4 16616, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports  
Network Service: Thunderbolt Ethernet, Ethernet, en4  
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0  
PCI Card: Apple 57762-A0, Ethernet Controller, Thunderbolt@195,0,0  
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM1024F, 1 TB  
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus  
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad  
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub  
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller  
USB Device: Hub  
USB Device: Microsoft¬Æ 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0  
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.2  
Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter, Apple Inc., 1, 5.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have removed FortiClient it has resolved the same issue for me.

Checking the Fortinet forums and our service tickets shows this issue is an incompatibility with the client and no El Capitain support as yet and no eta.

Comment: Thanks for this @Jamitupya. I have since uninstalled FortiClient and had no issues.